# Comparing a list/set of objects efficiently

Tags: java, list, oop, set, software-design

I am trying to compare two `Fact` data structures.

Each `Fact` is made up of a predicate and a list of arguments

```
private String predicate;
private ArrayList<Argument> arguments;
```

The `Argument` class is made up of a variable and a symbol

```
String variable;
argTypes symbol;

public enum argTypes {
    STRING, EQ, GT, LT, MATCHONE, MATCHALL, VAR
}
```

There are two subclasses `numericArgument` and `stringArgument`

```
private boolean isNeg;
private int value; //or private String value if stringArgument
```

Examples of numeric arguments: `length = 10, length != 10, length > 10, length < 10`

Examples of string arguments: `length = long, length != long`

arguments may also have value of `?` (matches on exactly one argument) , `*` (matches on 0 or more arguments) , `&x` (a variable) - I construct these as the generic Argument type, setting their appropriate `symbol` field

So onto the matching! Examples of good matches:

`cat(height = tall, colour = black, length=30)` with `cat(height = tall, colour = black, length>20)`

`cat(black)` `cat(!brown)`

`Cat(fur = soft, colour = brown, size = 10)` matches `Cat(fur = soft, *)`

Example of bad match:

`Cat(fur = soft, colour = brown, size = 10)` with `Cat(fur = soft, colour = brown)` [missing arguments define a different predicate altogether]

I have implemented methods to match two `Argument` object but am struggling to implement a good method to compare two `Fact` object. I have experimented with using a Hashset and LinkedHashSet instead the arguments arraylist. I have also tried adding a `containsMatchAll` field to `Fact` instead of including the `*` within the argument list.

I would be so grateful for advice on ways to overhaul this data structure so that matching is not super slow.

Thank you!

Comment: How would you compare: `cat(height = tall, colour = black, length>20)` with `cat(height = tall, colour = black, length>30)` ?

Comment: @alfasin No match!

Comment: This means that your "comparison" is not transitive, because both of them would match: `cat(height = tall, colour = black, length=40)`. Since the comparison is not transitive (you cannot apply linear order) it make the problem a totally different one than just figuring out the right data-structure.

Comment: Oh interesting! Tbh, things are very unclear from the specifications given. Supposing comparison is indeed transitive, what do you suggest please?

Comment: but you just said that it's *not* transitive...

Comment: It doesn't matter how you keep the arguments, for each `argTypes` you'll have to implement its own "comparison logic" which will return a boolean value. Another thing that is not clear to me: if argTypes is `EQ` does it mean that it's `MATCHONE` ? `MATCHALL` ? how can EQ and MATCHALL even be in the same category ? you should ask for clarifications and try to come up with different (and not such straightforward) use-cases

Comment: Okay, so I should have made that more clear. I have implemented comparison logic for each argType. By `EQ` I mean `x = 10`, By MATCHONE I mean `?`, by MATCHALL I mean `*`. I have the freedom to change the categories, but I will be parsing a simple string sequences just like the above examples, turning them into `fact` predicates and doing pairwise comparisons as part of an expert system.

Comment: I really appreciate how thorough you have been @alphasin - it definitely has raised some questions that I have to check with my supervisor! So given these additional clarifications, how do you suggest I proceed please, given I have nearly absolute freedom?

Comment: As a first stab I would change `argTypes` to be an interface where each and every type would extend it and have its own "compare" method implemented differently. What is `predicate` is also unclear. Ignoring it, it sounds like you want to be able to compare two Facts X and Y by comparing each two arguments they have, say: X.a against Y.b iff these arguments have the same `variable` name, right ?

Comment: Okay, so right now I have it implemented as superclass `Argument`, with those subclasses `stringArgument` and `numericArgument` with their own compare method - but Argument as an interface does seem to make more sense. `predicate` does seem to be mislabelled - I should change that to `predicateName` but you are right two facts are the same if `predicateName` is the same and their arguments match, and for their arguments to match they must have the same variable names (unless we are comparing against `?` or `*` arguments)

Comment: Sounds like a good start, go on!

Comment: Given this - 1.  what data structure do you recommend i encode `Fact.arguments` in, 2. is there a good trick to speedup the comparison of the two Facts? 3. How do you suggest I deal with `*`, `?` arguments? Thank you again!

Comment: 1/2. I wouldn't worry about efficiency at this stage, first try to implement it just so that it works, then worry about improvements. You may want, in later iteration, to save the Arguments in a HashMap so that `length` is the key and the value can be `10` or `<10` and etc. This will speed up you comparisons because you want to compare `length` of one Fact only against a `length` of another Fact (you don't want to compare it against `colour` for example). As for #3: I'm not clear about the difference between ? and *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider converting

```
private ArrayList<Argument> arguments;
```

into a map, say

```
private HashMap<String, Argument> arguments;
```

Where, each entry into the map is a key : value pair consisting of the argument/variable name and the value being the Argument reference.

Then, when comparing the Arguments of two different objects, you can just iterate over the keys of the first object's Argument map:

```
if (object1.getArguments().size() != object2.getArguments.size()) {
   ... // they don't even have the same number of arguments, this is the first check
} else {

    for(String variableName : object1.getArguments().keySet()) {
        if(!object2.getArguments().contains(variableName)) {
            ... // bad match !
            break;
        } else {
           Argument arg1 = object1.getArguments().get(variableName);
           Argument arg2 = object2.getArguments().get(variableName);
           ... // do some comparison here
        }
    }
}
```

This has the added bonus that you can prevent objects from containing duplicate variables with the same name.

This is actually a design decision you, the programmer, should take. I should add a disclaimer that this is not the only solution to this problem, this is just one of them, but a convenient one for the operations you want to perform.

Comment: Thank you, that does seem like a possible solution. However, although there will never be duplicate `Argument` objects, it is perfectly possible for there to be multiple arguments with the same variable name i.e. `height < 10`, `height > 5`, so I'm not quite sure a hashmap would work for my case. Also do you mind suggesting how I should deal with the `?` (match on one variable) and `*` (match on ≥0 variables) wildcards please? Would appreciate your input @alfasin too please, on that last q

Comment: @joelross Okay I see. In that case you may use a map<String, List<Args>>. Otherwise as Pure ArrayLists you'd have a quadratic runtime complexity. Also, you could consider adding a wildcard class for the same thing.